# How do I upload a picture to a local folder using multer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I'm a student and I have a project to create a simple website. I'm trying to make a website, where the user can create some kind of listing and upload a picture to it (kind of like ebay), as well as the ability to create user profile, and upload a picture to it. But I've been struggling for the past day and a half on how to upload the picture. I'm a beginner in JS and I've been reading lots of articles and documentation but I can't really wrap my head around it. So I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

In an MVC structure:

config/

controllers/

models/

public/

views/listing/

app.js

package.json

---

### app.js:

```
    const express = require('express');
    const config = require('./config/config');
    const app = express();

    let env = 'development';
    require('./config/database')(config[env]);
    require('./config/express')(app, config[env]);
    require('./config/passport')();
    require('./config/routes')(app);

    module.exports = app;
```

---

### views/listing/create.hbs

-- Creates a new listing (title, content, upload picture)

```
     <!-- ...-->  
    <div>Upload your item's picture:<div>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="file" name="image">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
     <!-- ...-->
```

---

### config/routes.js

```
    const listingController = require('./../controllers/listing');
    module.exports = (app) => {
       app.get('/listing/create', listingController.createGet);
       app.post('/listing/create', listingController.createPost);
       // ...
    }
```

---

### controllers/listing.js

```
    module.exports = {
     // ...
     createPost: (req, res) => {
     let args = req.body;
     //listing creation logic...
     //.. some checks and database action
       if(err){
        //redirect to home with error message
        } else {           
            // I tried to add the uploading logic here
           res.redirect('/');
        }
     }
   }
  // ...
```

---

And this is what I came up with after watching tutorials and searching,
I tried placing it in numerous locations and playing with it as best as I could as well as changing the path, but nothing worked.

```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    var multer = require('multer');

    var upload = multer({
         dest: __dirname + "/public/uploads/"
    });

   // I don't really know if this executes completely
    router.post('listing/create', upload.single('image'), function(req, res, next){         
          // These two don't get executed
          res.send(req.file);
          console.log(req.file);
    })
```

I also tried to create another js file and place this there, then reference it, also tried to place it in app.js and in routes.js, none of which were successful.

I must also say that I'm new to HTML as well. I tried playing with the action="" attribute, and match it to different routes, but nothing worked. I'm missing some serious knowledge here and I'd be really grateful if someone can give me a hand on this one! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need create the storage with Multer and specify the folder on the controller with a Global Scope:

```
// var storage = multer.memoryStorage(); // FOR MEMORY STORAGE
var storage =   multer.diskStorage({  // DISK STORAGE
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './docs');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    var fileExtensionPatter = /\.([0-9a-z]+)(?=[?#])|(\.)(?:[\w]+)$/;
    var extension = file.originalname.match(fileExtensionPatter)[0];
    if(extension === '.pdf' || extension === '.PDF'){
      callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + '.pdf');
    } else if (extension === '.txt' || extension === '.TXT'){
      callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + '.txt');
    } else if (extension === '.docx' || extension === '.DOCX'){
      callback(null, file.filename + '-' + Date.now() + '.docx');
    }
  }
});
var upload = multer({ storage : storage}).single('doc');
```

Then you need to call this upload function from the function that receive the POST with the multipart data:

```
router.post('/upload', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
  upload(req,res,function(err) {
      if(err) {
          console.log(err);
          return res.end("Error uploading file.");
      }
      // DO YOUR STUFF
});
```

So, remember put the METHOD="POST" and the ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" on your form, and the name "doc" (the same name that you define on upload function) on your name parameter:

```
<form class="form-group" action="/api/v1/quotes/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="PDF">
      <label> Drop the PDF file </label>
      <input type="file" name="doc">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Why do I have to create the storage with multer, @Andoni? Can't I just point to a local folder? I tried to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2y9Nl04B2UA) tutorial, and there he doesn't create a storage, is there something else to it?

Comment: @J.o'D. The [docs of Multer specify for storage](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#storage) : "The disk storage engine gives you full control on storing files to disk." I think that if you not specified the storage, the file will uploaded to the /tmp folder. That code that I put above it's mine and works fine with Multer on "^1.2.1"

Comment: I see, I checked the default /tmp direnctories, which under windows are 2 - UserName\AppData\Local\Temp and C:\Windows\Temp. I tried to find  the image there, but it didn't show up, which means it was never sent. So the problem maybe lies elsewhere.

Comment: @J.o'D. Why don't you want use the storage option? I'm thinking about the version of Multer. I believe that on a deprecated version of Multer you don't need the storage option. Please, follow this tutorial https://codeforgeek.com/2014/11/file-uploads-using-node-js/ they use storage option. Regards.

Comment: Ок, @Andoni, I will try the storage option and will keep you updated on the results. Thanks for the help!